# Symfony2 when extending the template from the base template its overriding the base template links

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Issue Facing - I do have the Base Template with some CSS and JS links, I have created a view page for which I want to add some CSS links which are only specific to this view page and no others view pages, this view page extends from this Base Template.  When I add the some CSS links to the view page its Overriding the Base Template CSS and JS files.

Any solution will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

The following is the snippet of my BaseTemplate -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>{% block title %}Login Page{% endblock %}</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-theme.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/signin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
{% endblock %}
</head>
...
```

And following is my view page where I am extending from that Base Template -

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
<div class="container">

    <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="{{ path("user_auth_homepage") }}" method="POST">
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>

      <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="" type="email">
      <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input value="remember-me" type="checkbox" name="remember_me"> Remember me
      </label>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to inherit and extend a block from parent template you should use {{ parent() }} function like this :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
```

You can read more detail's in  [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your page template do as following:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <link href="your_new_css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endblock %}
```

It will print parent content of the `stylesheets` block and apply your new styles

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add a specific `CSS` Links and also inherit `CSS` Links from Base layout

Just use [parent()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html)  method in your view page

EX:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <link href="{{ asset('') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
```

**Without** `parent()` method into View Page will override all your `CSS` Links into Base Layout

Answer (score 0):

In the base template move the css links outside of the twig block

```
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}Login Page{% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-theme.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/signin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />

    {% block stylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

These stylesheets will be available in all pages and your view template can add additional stylesheets.